# Multiple entry points within the same conda environment

Tags: python, click, conda, setuptools, entry-point

I'm trying to create a second entry point within my conda env. The reason for this is that both packages use the same environment.yml but are separate packages, there is no other overlap than the environment.

These entry points define the starting point for my Click commands (cli.py within the scripts directory) I have for the specific package. Yet once I activate my environment and try to run the click command for the second package (mypackage2) installed during the **projects-setup** step in the Makefile I get a **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.cli2'**. The package1's click commands work completely fine.

#### Project Structure

```
/projects
    /src
        /mypackage1
            /scripts
                cli.py
                ...
            /tests
            README.md
            setup.py
        /mypackage2
            /scripts
                cli2.py
                ...
            /tests
            README.md
            setup.py
    environment.yml
    Makefile
```

#### setup.py

Each of the packages has a separate setup.py file.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="mypackage1",
    version="0.1",
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    entry_points="""
        [console_scripts]
        mypackage1=scripts.cli:cli
    """,
)
```

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="mypackage2",
    version="0.1",
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    entry_points="""
        [console_scripts]
        mypackage2=scripts.cli2:cli
    """,
)
```

#### Makefile

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

setup: env-setup module-setup

env-setup:
    conda env update -f environment.yml
    source activate projects && python -m ipykernel install --user --name projects

module-setup: projects-setup

projects-setup: 
    source activate projects && pip install -e src/mypackage1 && pip install -e src/mypackage2
```

A couple of things I've tried and looked at are:

- Only installing one package to see if there were errors in the package's setup somewhere, but both function fine.
- Changed file and directory naming to see if that had any effect.

Not sure what else to look at or try. Everything seems to match the Click documentation. 
Can you only have one entry point within the environment?

Any help is appreciated!